# I can not set margin-right in React

Tags: css, reactjs, margin

I am developing a portfolio web site but I got a problem. I can not move my picture into right side of the screen its look like this :

[What its look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYcyf.png)

but I want to do that like this :

[What i wanna got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdNSL.png)

**I just used react js to do this I can not use flex or flex-block to do this because its need to be mobile responsive**

So here the JavaScript code i used:

```
import React from 'react'
import './intro.css';
import bg from '../../Assets/intro.png'
import { Link } from 'react-scroll';
import WorkIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Work';



const Intro = () => {
  return (
    <section id="intro">

      <div className="introContent">

        <span className="hello">Hello,</span>
        <span className="inroText">I'm <span className="introName">Thinura</span> <br />Web Developer</span>
        <p className="introPara">I am a skilled web designer with experience in creating visually appealing and user friendly websites.</p>
          <Link><button className="btn"> <WorkIcon/>Hire Me</button></Link>
      </div>
    


      <img src={bg} alt="" className="bg" />

    </section>
  )
}

export default Intro
```

And here is the CSS i used:

```
#intro{
    height: calc(100vh  - 4rem) ;
    width: 100vh;
    max-width: 75rem;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}


.bg{
    position: absolute;
    top: -4rem;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 100vh;
 
}
```

Can you please tell me what is the error with my website it will be a lot help!!

I am expecting the most suitable answer for this it should me mobile responsive!

and I am gonna Appreciated your help

Comment: *I can not use flex or flex-block to do this because its need to be mobile responsive* - why wouldn't flex be mobile responsive?

Comment: it's hard to maintain